# React Native useEffect() not triggered with firebase and onAuthStateChanged

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I have an app using react native and firebase. In the App.js I have a useEffect wrapper observing onAuthStateChanged to display either the registration/login or app views if the user object is present.

In the **registrationView** I have a

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

const register = useCallback(async () => {
    try{
      await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((registerresponse) => {          
            const user = registerresponse.user.uid;
            setUserData(user);
        })

    } catch(error) {

      /..some error coding.../

      setError(msg);

      console.error(error.message);
    }
  }, [email, password, error, userData]);
```

And a callback useEffect to do some database work:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (userData) {
      
      try{

        setDoc(doc(db, "user", userData), {
          username: username,
          country: country
        });

        console.log("User Registered");

      }catch(error) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }

    }
  }, [userData]);
```

The issue I figured out is that because as I have the observer on the App.js that changes the View immediately after the user object is present, the useEffect on the registrationView is never fired. The app immediately navigates to the home screen but database work is not done.

So basically the question is, how do I keep the onAuthStateChanged pending until the useEffect has been done. OR is there a better way to handle post registration work as middleware before route transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to delay the calling of your `onAuthStateChanged` callback.

The idiomatic approach is to put all code that needs to run when the user has signed in into the `onAuthStateChanged` callback. So you'd call `setUserData(user);` from there, rather from from the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` callback as you now do.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I guess the issue would be how to identify if a user is a new registered user OR an existing user logging in as the `onAuthStateChanged` won't. This could be done with an `user.metadata.creationTime`check but maybe not ideal.  

I also figured out that I could also just run the db function directly inside the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. The callback with a state seems not needed.